# Breaking Links to Excel for PowerPoint Charts

Tags: hyperlink, powerpoint, break

I wrote a code to break links to the source excel file for my powerpoint deck, the macro works well except for 2 charts. Both the charts are on the same slide (which is not uncommon) and are line charts. The charts need to be manually updated but the data resides in a excel file only. Not sure what am I missing. This is the code that I wrote

```
Sub SavePPT()

Dim objPP As Object
Dim objPPFile As Object
Dim sld As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim shp1 As Chart
Dim newshp As Shape
Dim pptChart As Object

Set objPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPP.Visible = True

Set objPPFile = objPP.ActivePresentation
objPPFile.Save

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each sld In objPPFile.Slides
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
If shp.HasChart Then
shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
On Error GoTo 0
End If
Next
Next

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each sld In objPPFile.Slides
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Or shp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
On Error GoTo 0
End If
Next
Next


objPPFile.SaveAs ("Location" _ & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".pptx")
                                                                    
objPPFile.Close
objPP.Quit

Set pptChart = Nothing
Set objPPFile = Nothing
Set objPP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart might be in a placeholder, in which case none of your code will act upon it. If the shape's .Type = msoPlaceholder (ie, 14), check the shape's .PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType property to see if it's a linkedOleobject or .HasChart etc.

BTW, an msoEmbeddedOLEObject  won't have a .LinkFormat object to call on; I suspect you have some error handling code that's obscuring an error there. In any case, I'd limit that check to just msoLinkedOLEObject.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help. I realized it later that those 2 slides have a lot of text boxes on them and when I consolidate some of those textboxes the issue was resolved.